# what is the consistency level of a batch get in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, consistency, eventual-consistency

Does get(Iterable  e) return strongly consistent data or eventually consistent data.
I have looked at the documentation but haven't found the answer.

Comment: The pragmatic consistency of *any* "data store" depends entirely on how the data gets there, and whether-or-not it might be subject to modification such that whatever is in the store is "stale upon-arrival." It is a shared resource that must be treated as ... a shared resource.  The usual caveats apply, "Google or not."

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

A batch get (say 500 items), makes no consistency guarantees outside of the individual entities. In other words, it has the same consistency as doing 500 individual lookups, where each entity get will be strongly consistent. Transactions are atomic, so you will not see partial transactions.

## Longer Answer

A current implementation detail (subject to change), is that a batch get will be will be strongly consistent for entities in the same [Entity Group](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#transactions_and_entity_groups).

Between Entity Groups, it will be subject to eventual consistent.

**As an example, consider the following:**

You send a request from client A (cA) to delete 5 entities from entity group 1 (eg1), wrapped in a transaction (tx1). After it commits, you issue a second request from cA to write 5 entities to entity group 2 (eg2), also wrapped in a transaction (tx2).

Client B (cB) goes a batch get for those 10 entities at roughly the same time.

Possible results include:

- All 10 entities are returned

  - *eg1 is read before tx1 commit, eg2 is read after tx2 commit*
- No entities are returned

  - *eg1 is read after tx1 commit, eg2 is read before tx2 commit*
- 5 entities from eg1 are returned

  - *eg1 is read before tx1 commit, eg2 is read before tx2 commit*
- 5 entities from eg2 are returned

  - *eg1 is read after tx1 commit, eg2 is read after tx2 commit*

Note, at no time are results from partial transactions returned, since Cloud Datastore transactions are atomic.